# mod-rewrite rules executing out of order

Tags: mod-rewrite

Okay, so I have two separate mod-rewrite rules in my vhost block. The first rule redirects a customer offsite if they come in thru an affiliate URL such as example.com/1234.html and the second rule forces the URL to always contain www dot like www.example.com.

```
# Affiliate Links
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\.html$ http://affiliates.example.com/log.php?id=$1 [R=302,L]

# Ensure we are always on www dot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.loc [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

The rules themselves work great. The problem is that if the first rule applies I want it to immediately redirect, however it seems as if the second rule is hoisted to the top because it always takes precedence. What do I need to change so that these execute in order?

Comment: Try clearing your browsers cache first. I'm assuming here the rules are places inside your <Virtualhost> section, of you apache config files!? What happens if you just swap them around?

Comment: They are in the virtualhost block and I'm doing an apache restart after every modification and opening up a new private browsing session for testing. They are currently in the order I would like them to execute, but switching them around does not change the behavior. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

You've stated that this is in a vhost block. In that context (as opposed to, for example, an .htaccess file) URLs always start with '/'

Thus

```
 RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\.html$ http://affiliates.example.com/log.php?id=$1 [R=302,L]
```

should instead be

```
 RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)\.html$ http://affiliates.example.com/log.php?id=$1 [R=302,L]
```

(ie, with the leading slash), otherwise it will never match anything.